# how re-login to a aws token expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, cloud

Error when retrieving token from sso: Token has expired and refresh failed

How can i refresh my token when

```
aws sso session login --sso-session prod
```

does not work

it gets me the next:
`(base) kigo_max@hp-ubuntu-max:~$ aws sso session login --sso-session prod

usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

get-role-credentials                     | list-account-roles
list-accounts                            | logout
login                                    | help

`

Answer (score 1):

There is no **session** as a subcommand of the `aws sso` command.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sso/index.html

Use this

```
aws sso login --profile prod
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-using-profile.html#sso-using-profile-sign-in

Comment: Okey, I already try that:

(base) kigo_max@hp-ubuntu-max:~$ aws sso login --profile prod
Note: AWS CLI version 2, the latest major version of the AWS CLI, is now stable and recommended for general use. For more information, see the AWS CLI version 2 installation instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

Comment: The reason why "aws sso login --profile prod" fails is probably because the AWS CLI version is not up to date.
Please bring the CLI(version2) up to date and re-run the command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html